# Letting only the abstract class know about its inheritors

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a payment system for my site. Users can select one of several payment providers to pay, but all should behave in the same way. I thought to represent this behavior like this:

```
public abstract class PaymentProvider {
    private static var methods = Dictionary<String,PaymentProvider>
    {
        {"paypal",new PaymentProviderPaypal()},
        {"worldpay",new PaymentProviderWorldpay()}
    }

    public static Dictionary<String,PaymentProvider> AllPaymentProviders
    {
        get {return methods;}
    }

    public abstract pay();
}

public class PaymentProviderPaypal : PaymentProvider {
    public override pay() {

    }
}

public class PaymentProviderWorldpay : PaymentProvider {
    public override pay() {

    }
}
```

You are supposed to use this by writing `PaymentProvider.AllPaymentProviders["key"].pay()`. The idea is that the functions using this class don't need to know about how the underlying payment provider is implemented, they just need to know the key.

However, at the moment, if you have access to the `PaymentProvider` class, you also have access to the inheriting classes. Its possible to instantiate a new copy of the inheriting classes, and make use of them in an unexpected way. I want to encapsulate the inheriting classes so that only the abstract `PaymentProvider` knows about them.

How should I do this? Different protection levels like `protected` don't work here - In Java, `protected` means that only other classes in the namespace can use that class, but in C# it means something else.

Do I have the right idea here? Or should I use a different method?

Comment: Not an answer to the question: In .NET `internal` gives access to everything in the current assembly (all namespaces), `protected` is only accessible to inheritors.

Comment: What's the added benefit of having to rely on the user knowing which key to use to pass to `AllPaymentProviders` over making the types public?

Comment: @Jamiec I saw that on MSDN. However, the site is a 'website' project under visual studio, and this does with things with assemblies, so I didn't want to use 'internal' incase something unexpected happened.

Comment: Also not an answer: even in Java, `protected` is more to do with inheritance than packages.

Comment: @StevenJeuris The inheritors can have different settings in their constructors, such as turning on test transactions for the providers, and changing ids/passwords/settings. I want to have all these initialized in one place (probably in a config file eventually) rather than letting people have access to them to instantiate them however they feel like. I can document which keys are valid so users know the right one to call.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think there was some way in Java to do it based on packages though - maybe if you use no access keyword at all?

Comment: @Oliver: Yes, without any explicit access modifier it's "package private".

Comment: @Oliver: In that case I would use one of the solutions as Jon Skeet suggested. I wouldn't however rely on the keys to initiate your providers but use the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options spring to mind:

- Put this in a separate assembly from the client code, and make the implementations abstract
- Put the implementations inside the `PaymentProvider` class as private nested classes. You can still separate the source code by making `PaymentProvider` a partial class - use one source file per implementation

The first option is likely to be the cleanest if you don't mind separating the clients from the implementation in terms of assemblies.

Note that both of these are still valid options after the change proposed by Jamiec's answer - the "visibility" part is somewhat orthogonal to the inheritance part.

(As an aside, I hope the method is really called `Pay()` rather than `pay()` :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'll go with your second suggestion. The structure of the site at the moment doesn't lend itself to putting the payment code in a different assembly ( Something I plan to fix eventually.)

Answer (score 2):

Your inheritance heirachy is a bit wonky, I would be tempted to do it a similar but crucially different way.

```
public interface IPaymentProvider
{
  void Pay()
}

// Implementations of IPaymentProvider for PaypalPaymentProvider & WorldpayPaymentProvider

public static class PaymentHelper
{
    private static var providers = Dictionary<String,IPaymentProvider>
    {
        {"paypal",new PaymentProviderPaypal()},
        {"worldpay",new PaymentProviderWorldpay()}
    }


    public static void Pay(string provider)
    {
        if(!providers.Containskey(provider))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid provider: " + provider);

        providers[provider].Pay();
    }

}
```

Then the usage would be something like `PaymentHelper.Pay("paypal")`.

Obviously if there is more data to provide to the `Pay` method this can be added to both the interface, and the helper. for example:

```
public interface IPaymentProvider
{
  void Pay(double amount);
}

public static void Pay(string provider, double amount)
{
    if(!providers.Containskey(provider))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid provider: " + provider);

    providers[provider].Pay(amount);
}
```

Comment: Why is it better to use an interface rather than an abstract class? Does it make it more maintainable/faster?

Comment: No difference really - the only reason to use an abstract class is if you have some base implementation - I used an interface for demonstration purposes.